# App publishing - stuck at processing

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am planning to push my app to the play store for the next update. I tried of uploading. it has stuck at processing after uploading. Kindly help me with the solution. it has been 1 hr as of now, still processsing

it has been 3 days, no solution as of now. their support team response is too casual and slow.

I observed that it throws 503 error when it tries to upload it on google play server.

Kindly let me know if anybody has observed such behaviour.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many times did you tried? Did you try to close your browser and open again and repeat the process? Because processing is generally takes 0 to 2 minutes.

Comment: I tried atleast 20-30 times, with different browser, tried removing cookies and caches, waited for more than 1 hr for this processing to be finished. Still no help